# How to change the format of a recyclerview row due to change in livedata?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I have a standard app setup (Activity, ViewModel, Repository). The Activity contains a RecyclerView. The RecyclerView has an adapter. In my Activity I update the RecyclerView by observing a LiveData object:

```
 mQuizViewModel.getCurrentQuizTask().observe(this, new Observer<QuizTask>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(QuizTask quizTask){
                adapter.setAnswers(quizTask.getAnswers());
                }
        });
```

If the user hits any item of my RecyclerView the quizTask will be changed and will fire in turn a onChanged event. Depending on which item the user has hit I want to change the font color of a few items of the RecyclerView. To do so I need a reference to each row from the above mentioned observe method within the Activity. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem quite easily. I change the color in the onBindViewHolder method of the adapter. I added a field in the class of the object which is passed to the adapter via

```
adapter.setData(DataToPass)
```

In the onBindViewHolder method I check with the additional information wrapped in DataToPass if conditions are fullfilled to change the text color.